# PHP namespace PDO not found

Tags: php, pdo, namespaces

I'm facing an issue I unfortunatly could not resolve so far. I created a `database class` into `app/db/mysql/database.php` with the following content :

```
<?php
    namespace App\Database;
    use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

    class Database{
        private static $connection = null;

        private function __construct( $host, $base, $user, $pass ){
            try{
                self::$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$base", $user, $pass);
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        public static function get(){
            if( self::$connection !== null ){
                return self::$connection;
            }
            $yaml = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents(realpath('./app') . '/database.yml'));
            self::$connection = new Database( $yaml['host'], $yaml['base'], $yaml['user'], $yaml['pass'] );
        }
    }
```

Using composer, I'm autoloading this class :

```
{
    "autoload" : {
        "classmap" : [
            "app/libraries",
            "app/db"
        ]
    }
}
```

Which generate an `autoload_classmap.php` such as :

```
return array(
    'App\\Database\\Database' => $baseDir . '/app/db/mysql/database.php',
    'App\\Libraries\\Parser' => $baseDir . '/app/libraries/Parser.php',
);
```

Now, when everything works fine, I'm always getting an error related to PDO :

```
Fatal error: Class 'App\Database\PDO' not found in /var/www/my_application/app/db/mysql/database.php on line 24
```

I think the problem comes from `namespace` because when I put the class into the index page, I don't have any error. PDO is installed and works.

Comment: Oh, I see you solved that yourself. Deleting my answer

Comment: @DamienPirsy better restore it. Either whole question have to be deleted or have an answer, to reduce unanswered questions list.

Comment: Deleting the question sounds better to me (since it could have been avoided in the first place), or OP could provide himself the answer and autoaccept it

Comment: I've removed the answer from the question as it should be an answer by itself (and we already have one accepted).

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You should be using correct namespaces for the objects in your methods, either "use" them or prefix them with the root namespace;

```
<?php
//... namespace etc...

use \PDO;

self::$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$base", $user, $pass);
```

or simply;

```
self::$connection = new \PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$base", $user, $pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use PDO then you should add the line `use PDO` in the file where you are going to use the class PDO Ford example in file where you create object PDO and in each the file of model.

Comment: Please do not duplicate existing answers