# autoload PDO with namespaces

Tags: php, pdo, namespaces, autoload

There is a class called DB in my PHP project which contains this code which works:

```
namespace classes\utility;

use \PDO;

class DB
{

    /*object constructor*/      # connect to database
    private function __construct()
    {
        try
        {
            $conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=' . DB_HOST . ';Database=' . DB_NAME);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);     //to capture error messages returned by db
            $this->setPdo($conn);
            // echo 'connected';    //enable this line to test db connection
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The following autoloader is located in index.php:

```
# autoload classes (this uses an anonymous function)
spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
        // echo $className . '<br>';
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName  = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
        // echo '<br>autoload: ' . $fileName . '<br>';
    require $fileName;
});
```

When these modifications are made to the DB class: remove `use \PDO;` and put a backslash infront of PDO constructor like so `$conn = new \PDO('sqlsrv:Server=' . DB_HOST . ';Database=' . DB_NAME);` as recommended in this post: [PHP namespace PDO not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699319/php-namespace-pdo-not-found) then the code fails.  The messages are: 
**Warning: require(classes\utility\PDO.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\OOP\index.php on line 40**

**Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'classes\utility\PDO.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\OOP\index.php on line 40**

Why doesn't this work?  I would prefer to exclude the use statement and have PHP autoload PDO by having a backslash in the PDO constructor.

Comment: Hi. If you want to remove the use instruction, you need to add the backslash before any occurrence of PDO, which includes all the PDO:: on the next line. We will also need more code to be 100% accurate.

Comment: @Thomas - I tried adding backslashes like this `$conn->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` but still get the same result.  I also tried adding a backslash infront of PDOException (not sure if one belongs there or not) but to no avail.  What am I missing?  Also, what is meant by needing to add more code to be 100% accurate?

Comment: Figured it out.  The code posted above for the DB class is just part of the class.  There was a PDO:: in the query() method later in the class which also needed a backslash.  No backslashes were necessary infront of PDOException.

Comment: I see no reason to remove `use \PDO` (in fact, I'd say change it to `use \PDO, \PDOException;`. At least it means you don't have to go hunting for all the non-prefixed usages.